# python: Heat map of dictionary consisting of list of arrays

Tags: python, dictionary, heatmap

I have a dictionary named 'dict' that looks like this:

```
{'1005': [array1([3, 2, 5, 3, 4]), array2([1, 2, 5, 9, 0]), array3([4, 2, 6, 3, 2]), array4([2, 4, 6, 3, 2]), array5([3, 2, 5, 5, 2]), array6([1, 6, 4, 5, 1]), array7([3, 2, 4, 6, 2]), array8([3, 5, 2, 5, 2])]})

{'1006': [array1([1, 2, 5, 9, 0]), array2([4, 2, 6, 3, 2]), array3([2, 4, 6, 3, 2]), array4([3, 2, 5, 5, 2]), array5([1, 6, 4, 5, 1]), array6([3, 2, 4, 6, 2]), array7([3, 5, 2, 5, 2]), array8([3, 2, 5, 3, 4])]})
```

... etc. ...

Each of these arrayN is a histogramm of bins 1 to 5.

Now I would like to obtain a heatmap for each 'arrayN', where:

```
y = dict.key()

x = bin number of dict.value()

color/z = dict.value()
```

So in other words, the first point would be y = 1005, x = '1' and color/z = '3', second point y = 1005, x = '2', color/z = '2' etc.

Other recommendation of how to visualize this would also be very welcome.

Comment: just convert it (in a loop) to a single 2D array and pass keys as ticks labels to heatmap, thats all

Comment: can you provides two or three more points exact values ? I can't decide from where comes the `1` and `2` comes for `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be formulated like that:

```
def make_color_function(n):
    def color(y, x)
        # N and x are 1-based
        return data[y][n - 1][x - 1]
    return color

y_range = [1005, 1006]
x_range = [1, 5]
```

And then you use `make_color_function(1)` (if N == 1), `x_range` and `y_range` to visualize your data somehow.

If you want to tackle your problem seriously, take a look at numpy and matplotlib. With numpy, you get convenient indexing and with matplotlib you get possibility to visualize your data easily.